# why the subspace $[−1, 0) \cup (0, 1]$ is locally connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Taken from  Munkres book, Page no : $161$

The subspace $[−1, 0) \cup (0, 1]$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is not connected, but it is locally connected.

**My  doubt** : why the subspace $[−1, 0) \cup (0, 1]$ is locally connected ?

By the definition  of locally connected

> A space $X$ is said to be locally connected at $x$ if for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there is a connected neighborhood of $V$ of $x$ contained in $U$.

Here  i take  $x=0$  , neighborhood $U$ of $x$  will   be  $(0- \epsilon , 0 + \epsilon)$

Now   here im confused that how   can i find connected neighborhood of $V$ of $x$ contained in $U$?.

Comment: $0$ is not even a point in this space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $x_0\in[-1,0)\cup(0,1]$ and let $U$ be a neighborhood of $x_0$. Then:

- If $x_0\in(-1,0)$, and if $\varepsilon>0$ is such that $(x_0-\varepsilon,x_0+\varepsilon)\subset U$, then $(x_0-\varepsilon,x_0+\varepsilon)$ is a connected neighborhood of $x_0$ contained in $U$.
- If $x_0\in(0,1)$, and if $\varepsilon>0$ is such that $(x_0-\varepsilon,x_0+\varepsilon)\subset U$, then $(x_0-\varepsilon,x_0+\varepsilon)$ is a connected neighborhood of $x_0$ contained in $U$.
- If $x_0=-1$, and if $\varepsilon>0$ is such that $[-1,-1+\varepsilon)\subset U$, then $[-1,-1+\varepsilon)$ is a connected neighborhood of $x_0$ contained in $U$.
- If $x_0=1$, and if $\varepsilon>0$ is such that $(1-\varepsilon,1]\subset U$, then $(1-\varepsilon,1]$ is a connected neighborhood of $x_0$ contained in $U$.

Comment: This is not a complete proof, as you don’t do it for an arbitrary neighbourhood $U$ of $x_0$. But it can easily be fixed..

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Fact: if $X$ is locally connected and $O \subseteq X$ is open then $O$ is also locally connected in the subspace topology (if $x \in O$ and $U$ is any open neighbourhood of $x$ in $O$ then $U$ is also open in $X$ and so contains a connected  neighbourhood in $X$ (which is still a neighbourhood in $O$ as well).

And $[-1,0) \cup (0,1]$ is an open subset of the connected *and* locally connected space $[-1,1]$ (the relative complement of the closed $\{0\}$). QED.